# how to find two separate centroids in cross section ellipsoid

Tags: matlab

How can I find the centroid of left and right side part of ellipsoid to cross section plane. Here is the code.

```
[x,y,z]=ellipsoid(0,0,0,0.5,1,0.25,50);
direction = [1 0 0];

figure
h=surfl(x,y,z);
set(h,'facealpha',0.5)
shading interp 
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
hold on 
s=patch([1 -1 -1 1], [1 1 -1 -1], [0 0 0 0]) ;
rotate(s,direction,120)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a math question, not a question about programming. Try https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 1-form a new coordinate system on your plane 2- transform ellipsoid matrix to plane coordinate system 3- split ellipsoid matrix based on sign of  new Z components 4- find mean() of each new ellipsoid matrix in each column (center of mass for each part) 5-transform back to original coordinates